# Docusign API Recipients Rate Limiting

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I wanted to implement a modal where the envelope recipients would be listed with normal recipient data: name, email, status etc. This list would be displayed regardless of the envelope could be any status.

Every time, a user wanted to consult which recipients exist for a given envelope, he would click for example on an envelope icon and the recipients modal would open.

Ideally, it would call the GetRecipients endpoint of the eSignatureAPI to populate the modal on opening.

Is this behaviour considered polling?? As in my scenario, the information is fetched only on runtime and based on user action is it just bounded by 1000 hourly calls per account?

We don't intent to do **automatic polling**.

According to the Docusign documentation, this subject is not very clear and if it is a blocker for Go live.

Answer (score 0):

Reading what you wrote I would say it's not polling.
But, an automated system cannot easily know your intentions, so the rule is a bit strict. If you make the same API call to get the details of the same envelope more than once in 15 min - we determine this is polling.
Just ensure that when you test your app for the go-live review, you check different envelopes and/or wait longer than 15 minutes before tests.